# RestSharp encoding CSV response

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

So I'm calling a API with restSharp, I get csv data back. Problem is the response data is encoded with Windows-1252, so all Swedish letters disappear.

Is there any easy way to ensure the response get encoded correctly before I get my hands on it?

I have tried following the steps in this issue posted to github (https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1240), but I cant figure it out, it's my first time using restSharp and csv.

This is my code:

```
var jsonFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\svant\\source\\repos\\testSCB3Api\\testSCB3\\Data\\Json\\question.json"));

using (var client = new RestClient("https://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/BE/BE0101/BE0101H/FoddaK"))
{
    BornModel bornModel = new BornModel();

    var payload = jsonFile;
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddStringBody(payload.ToString(), DataFormat.Json);
    var response = client.PostAsync(request).Result.Content;
            
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(response))
    {
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(stringReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<BornModelMap>();
            var records = csvReader.GetRecords<BornModel>();
            // records.RemoveAt(0);

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                record.region = bornModel.region;
                record.kön = bornModel.kön;
                record.Levandefödda2016 = bornModel.Levandefödda2016;
                record.Levandefödda2017 = bornModel.Levandefödda2017;
                record.Levandefödda2018 = bornModel.Levandefödda2018;
                record.Levandefödda2019 = bornModel.Levandefödda2019;
                record.Levandefödda2020 = bornModel.Levandefödda2020;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Opening that URL in the browser returns JSON encoded using UTF8, not a CSV file with Windows-1252. Open your browser's Developer Tools, go to the Network tab and open the URL. When you inspect the response headers you'll see it's UTF8

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is unlikely but possible that POST requests may be returning Windows-1252.

Comment: Even then, if the server specified the encoding in the response headers, RestClient would decode the content correctly

Comment: Please post code that actually reproduces the problem. Right now there's no CSV in Windows-1252, there's a JSON response in UTF8. Post whatever is inside `question.json` so that others can reproduce the problem, receive whatever you receive and test for fixes

Comment: There was an issue in the CSV serializer that it ignored the configured culture somewhere. It's been merged some time ago. You can try the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a more proper way to set the character encoding inside the client somewhere, however to solve your problem fast, you can get RawBytes from the response and encode manually, albeit it is not a great workaround.

```cs
   ...
   request.AddStringBody(payload.ToString(), DataFormat.Json);

   Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
   var response = client.PostAsync(request).Result.Content;
   var responseString = encoding.GetString(response.RawBytes);
   
   using (var stringReader = new StringReader(responseString)){
   ...
```